# What do I need to do to get Hash.from_xml() to work?

Tags: ruby, xml, hash, activesupport

I installed 'ActiveSupport' and required 'active_support' in my code, but I get a "No Method Error" when I try to use the `Hash.from_xml()` method.

What am I missing?

```
$ gem list
```

returns:

```
\*** LOCAL GEMS \***

activesupport (3.2.6)  
bundler (1.1.4)  
i18n (0.6.0)  
json (1.7.3)  
mime-types (1.19)  
multi_json (1.3.6)  
rake (0.9.2.2)  
rest-client (1.6.7)  
rubygems-bundler (1.0.3)  
rvm (1.11.3.5)
```

And:

```
$ ruby -v
```

returns:

```
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
```

The contents of `file.rb` are:

```
require 'active_support'  
require 'rest-client'  
require 'json'  
token = "xxx"  
user = "xxx"  
survey_id = "xxx"  
responses_from_api = RestClient.get "https://survey.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/ControlPanel/api.php?Request=getLegacyResponseData&User=#{user}&Token=#{token}&Version=2.0&SurveyID=#{survey_id}&Format=XML"  
responses = Hash.from_xml(responses_from_api).to_json  
puts responses
```

And:

```
$ ruby file.rb
```

returns:

```
file.rb:8:in `<main>': undefined method `from_xml' for Hash:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just `require 'active_support'` doesn't do very much, you have to pull in the pieces sort of by hand. If you want all of ActiveSupport:

```
require 'active_support/all'
```

or if you just want the Hash extensions:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'
```