# Basics of parsing xml with Ox

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to get information out of XML with the ruby Ox library, which as its documentation says is much faster than Nokogiri and others commonly used. Unfortunately, while I could use Nokogiri thanks to the simplicity of xpaths, I'm not a pro in Ruby and can't figure out where I'm going wrong with hashes and Ox documents, and some sample code to get my head around would be really helpful.

I can find very little in the way of online tutorials and [its documentation is pretty concise/minimal](http://www.ohler.com/ox/), although if I was more familiar with XML parsing in general I wouldn't need it spelled out for me.

I'm not asking for anyone to do my work for me here but I really don't know where I can look for info/guidance/example code, and am unable to use Nokogiri for my current program.

Using simplexml I got a Hash which I could `puts` out:

```
xml_data = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body      #grab XML
data = XmlSimple.xml_in(xml_data, { 'KeyAttr' => 'name'})   #parse XML to hash
```

Using ox what I get is an `Ox::Document` which just `puts` out its own name:

```
xml_data = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body      #grab XML
data = Ox.parse(xml_data)                                   #parse XML (to hash??)
```

There doesn't seem to be a guided tour of any of these libraries and the documentation assumes knowledge of what it all means with no links to working example code to compare with.

My main learning resource at present is seeing the fundamentals at work here on StackOverflow, but partly due to the short name (which Google/typos gets confused with OS X) I can find very little of these... It looks well set-up to do what I want, but I can only find a question also highlighting the thin documentation but trying to write (not read) xml [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751804/generating-xml-with-cdata-using-ox).

I'm trying to get a name out of the following XML structure ([example xml](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?id=PMC1637560&db=pmc)) - specifically that of the *corresponding* author (or authors), indicated by `corresp` in the XML:

```
<pmc-articleset>
 <article xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" article-type="research-article">
  <front>
   <article-meta>
    <article-id pub-id-type="pmid">17060631</article-id>
    <article-id pub-id-type="pmc">1637560</article-id>
    <article-id pub-id-type="publisher-id">3908</article-id>
    <article-id pub-id-type="doi">10.1073/pnas.0603850103</article-id>
    <contrib-group>
     <contrib contrib-type="author">
      <name>
       <surname>Andricioaei</surname>
       <given-names>Ioan</given-names>
      </name>
      <xref rid="aff1" ref-type="aff"/>
      <xref ref-type="corresp" rid="cor1">*</xref>
     </contrib>
```

i.e. Ioan Andricioaei in the example. I thought regular expressions would be an ugly way to get it out since it's already labelled... It's part of a larger effort/program I'm making and would really appreciate some XML guidance here.

Comment: Use `Nokogiri`.. for this.

Comment: I can't due to incompatibilities between Roo and Nokogiri (as roo needs google_drive and google drive v 0.3.0 is incompatible with Nokogiri or something)

Comment: Try `Hash.from_xml(xml_data)` or `Hash.from_xml(xml_data.to_xml)` or change `xml_data` to `data`. I read it superficially, so maybe i misread the point.

Comment: @zishe `Nomethoderror: undefined method 'from_xml' for Hash:Class` I'm afraid (and  `Nomethoderror: undefined method 'from_xml' for #<String:0x739fb78>` for the second option)

Comment: try `require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'` according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479210/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-get-hash-from-xml-to-work)

Comment: http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/reading_huge_xml-rb/
I also found ox is 5 times faster than nokogiri while reading a large xml.
Plus I have a wrapper written which simply allows you to search through large xml using ox, allows you to iterate with specified element.
https://gist.github.com/amolpujari/5966431